# Success page not showing after checkout in Magento

Tags: magento, e-commerce, checkout

After the customer purchases a product the following happens:

**Through Payment Gateway:**

**After successful transaction, it redirects to success page which is empty**.
After failed transaction, it redirects to failure page and displays perfectly.

**Through COD:**
It redirects back to cart page, but order is being captured under Sales.

Also the customer and admin aren't able to receive the email notification on successful transfer whereas email is being notified for failure transactions.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an error in your code and can't see it. Make sure in your index.php file from the root directory:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

is not commented out.

Or, if you are on a linux machine and using apache, the logs are usually in /var/log/apache2/*. Check the files in there for PHP errors.